# Solving $y'=e^{-t}+y$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

i just need a hand starting this question.

I am asked to plot the direction field of $$y'=e^{-t}+y$$, and the $$\lim_{t\to\infty}y(t)$$.

My process so far:

1. Find the Equilibrium Solutions

I know to set $y'=0$, but I don't know if this works since this is also dependent on $t$.

$$y=-e^{-t}$$
[image]

The limit of this would be $0$.

So doe that mean my first equilibrium point is at $y=0$ a horizontal "line" at $y'$ and $y$ on the graph of $y'$ vs $y$?

or, would the graph $y=-e^{-t}$ as it appears on a $y$ vs $t$ graph be the 'zeros' on the $y'$ v $y$ chart?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I'm not sure which one, or why.
AFter this I need to know if derivatives are positive or negative in each quadrant but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, $$y'=e^{-t}+y$$is easy to solve, and the answer is $$y=-\frac{e^{-t}}{2}+Ce^{t}$$C is a constant, I plot the direction field by Mathematica:

f[t_,y_]=E^-t+y

StreamPlot[{1,f[t,y]},{t,-5,10},{y,-10,10},Frame->False,Axes->True,AspectRatio->1/GoldenRatio]

[image]

by the way, the answer is reference by [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8848/32700)

As for $\lim_{t\to\infty}y(t)$, I think it's depend on the initial conditions, maybe others have better solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Setting $y=e^tu$, we get
$$
(D-I)\left(e^tu\right)=e^tu'\implies y=e^t\int e^{-t}(D-I)y\,\mathrm{d}t\tag{1}
$$
The given equation says that $(D-I)y=e^{-t}$, so plugging into $(1)$
$$
\begin{align}
y
&=e^t\int e^{-t}e^{-t}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=e^t\left(C+\frac12-\frac12e^{-2t}\right)\\[6pt]
&=Ce^t+\sinh(t)\\[12pt]
&=y(0)\,e^t+\sinh(t)\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
Thus, we can answer the second part.

If $y(0)=-\frac12$, then $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}y=0$

If $y(0)\gt-\frac12$, then $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}y=+\infty$

If $y(0)\lt-\frac12$, then $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}y=-\infty$